# PostgreSQL query optimize

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(org.id), 
org.name,  
org.partner_id, 
pos.partner_id, 
pos.id, 
org.partner_offer_section_id,
pos.title,
pos.offer_value,
pos.offer_currency,

(SELECT user_info.email FROM user_info WHERE user_info.org_id=org.id ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1) as user_email,
(SELECT CONCAT(user_info.first_name,' ',user_info.last_name) FROM user_info WHERE user_info.org_id=org.id ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1) as name


FROM org
INNER JOIN partner_offer_section pos ON org.partner_offer_section_id = pos.id
WHERE org.partner_offer_section_id != 0 AND org.partner_id != 0
```

Here is the same subquery that is executing the twice the same query. I was trying to left join this query but the problem is when I left join I got a null value. I have to get one user name or user email insted of multiple users aginst org.

```
SELECT org.name,
org.partner_id,
org.partner_offer_section_id,
org.offer_applied_date,
partner_offer_section.title,
partner_offer_section.offer_value,
partner_offer_section.offer_currency,
user_info.email
FROM org
left join   (SELECT user_info.id, user_info.email,user_info.created, user_info.org_id FROM user_info WHERE role='Org Admin' LIMIT 1)  user_info on org.id = user_info.org_id
left join partner_offer_section on org.partner_offer_section_id = partner_offer_section.id
where org.partner_id = 1
```

Now I wanna optime this query instead of multiple same subqueries.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: You might want to look into lateral joins.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

You should join the table directly instead of doing a subquery. Bellow is the example, making a `JOIN` with the first table and the `LEFT` only with the last one. Also, `DISTINCT` applies to all columns, it's not a function, as user [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) pointed out

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    org.name,
    org.partner_id,
    org.partner_offer_section_id,
    org.offer_applied_date,
    partner_offer_section.title,
    partner_offer_section.offer_value,
    partner_offer_section.offer_currency,
    user_info.email
FROM org
    join partner_offer_section on org.partner_offer_section_id = partner_offer_section.id
    left join user_info on org.id = user_info.org_id
        and user_info.role='Org Admin'
where org.partner_id = 1
```